# how to create divi page programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

i am creating page programmatically in wordpress, which works fine no issue in that, what i need now, i want to create that page with `divi`, can anyone please help me how to create divi page programmatically ? i am using below code to create page, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated.

```
$my_post = array(
                            'post_type'     => 'page',
                            'post_name'     => $new_post_permalink,
                            'post_title'    =>  $titleContainsTag == '0' ? $new_title_post : $replace_title,
                            'post_content'  => $replace_content.$internalLinksString,
                            'post_author'   => $post_author,
                            'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        );   
$page_insert_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

Comment: You mean the content to be in page builder ?

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed yeah

Comment: you are taking content from any API? you want the content in text module or some other module ? 1 solution is to create page template from theme builder & follow the default procedure to create pages programmatically ( which you have already coded ). the content will automatically added in builder ( on page edit it will be shown in textarea but at frontend builder settings will be applied ).
theme builder documentation - https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/the-divi-theme-builder/

Comment: i want to create CMS page with divi programmatically